# There is no `/usr/local/php/bin/phpize` in my Server

Tags: php, imap

There is an example for configure the imap to PHP, I copied from Internet:

```
yum install -y libc-client-devel

/usr/local/src/centos-sdk/source2/php/php-5.6.30/ext/imap
/usr/local/php/bin/phpize

./configure -with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config -with-imap -with-imap-ssl -with-kerberos -with-libdir=lib64

make && make install

echo "extension=imap.so" >> /etc/php.ini

service php-fpm restart
```

But I can not find the `bin/` directory in the 3rd line:

```
/usr/local/php/bin/phpize
```

there only a `var/` directory under my CentOS 7 Server.

```
[root@localhost php]# ls
var
[root@localhost php]# pwd
/usr/local/php
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `php-devel` package (CentOS) :

```
yum install php-devel
```

Comment: I tried, but after install there still do not have `bin/`.

Comment: `phpize` should be installed now. Are you able to find it with `whereis phpize` or `find / -name phpize` ?

Comment: `find / -name phpize` helps for me, as result: `/usr/bin/php74/bin/phpize`